# Gunzip extract *.gz files to another location

Tags: gzip, gunzip

This code was written to extract multiple .tar files to another location and woks fine

```bash
ls -1 ${short_filename} \
| while read file; do \
  tar -zxvf "$file" -C ${pentaho_temp_path}/${sessionkey}; \
done
```

I want to do the same for .gz files on a Linux machine. My files have no whitespace in their names and they look like this:

```
xport_RAN_Maa_LIM_10.93.217.170_20220629030929.xml.gz
xport_RAN_Maa_LIM_10.93.217.170_20220630030936.xml.gz 
xport_RAN_Mau_MPU_10.188.83.138_20220629031403.xml.gz 
xport_RAN_Mau_MPU_10.188.83.138_20220630031444.xml.gz
```

Comment: [never ever parse the output of `ls`; not even with `-1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead): Filenames can have all kinds and numbers of line breaks in them! A `for file in ${short_filename}/*;` instead of the `ls .. | while read…` would be safer, shorter, faster and nicer to read!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show example values for `short_filename`. Instead of parsing the output of `ls` you should better use a `for` loop. The details depend on the value of `short_filename`.

Comment: filenames go not have breaks or example of the short_filename are: xport_RAN_Maa_LIM_10.93.217.170_20220629030929.xml.gz                         
xport_RAN_Maa_LIM_10.93.217.170_20220630030936.xml.gz                         
xport_RAN_Mau_MPU_10.188.83.138_20220629031403.xml.gz                         
xport_RAN_Mau_MPU_10.188.83.138_20220630031444.xml.gz

Comment: Please don't use comments to provide requested information. [Edit] your question instead. Please make clear in your question if the value of `short_filename` is a single filename, a directory name or a wildcard.

Comment: Is `$short_filename` a single filename, a pattern, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

gzip files do not contain "files"; just a stream of bytes. So, if you want to uncompress them, just `gzip -d --stdout "${file}" > "${target_directory}/${target_file}"`.

Notize that your script **only** works on `*.`**`tar`**`.gz`, already, because of the `-z` flag.

Comment: Maybe `gzip -d "${file}" > "${target_directory}/${file%.gz}"`

Comment: @Bodo as long as `${file}` doesn’t contain any path components.

Comment: Apologies for the other post was having trouble accessing it.....   The initial script was written for .tar.gz files.....

Comment: Marcus, this will not extract the compressed file in new file. You should use something like: `gzip -dc ....`

Comment: @RomeoNinov hey, thanks for coming over, you're right, I missed the `-c`! Sorry to hear your original answer got deleted :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller, welcome. No problem, my answer was wrong :D

Comment: @RomeoNinov was it? Because otherwise I'd say we ask OP to reopen on SU, move my answer there!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, IMHO in UNIX/Linux is better place for this Q/A :)

Answer (score 2):

Your script is needlessly complicated. Lines can be broken at both `|` and `do`, as well as after any command, so none of your `\`  are needed. The exact same script could be written like this:

```
ls -1 "$short_filename" | 
    while read file; do
        tar -zxvf "$file" -C "$pentaho_temp_path/$sessionkey"
    done
```

But that is a bad idea. As others have pointed out, parsing `ls` is very fragile and should be avoided. It is also pointless in this case, since all you need for the above script is:

```
for file in "$short_filename"/*; do
    tar -zxvf "$file" -C "$pentaho_temp_path/$sessionkey"
done
```

But since your files are all just `.gz` and not tarred, you don't need `tar` at all and can just do:

```
for file in "$short_filename"/*; do
    zcat "$file" > "$pentaho_temp_path/$sessionkey"/"$(basename "$file" .gz)"
done
```

Comment: yeah, zcat is probably the rightest tool

Comment: +1 zcat, and maybe background each process will leverage resource usage, also use basename to avoid the full path in $file: for file in "$short_filename"/*.gz; do zcat "$file" > "$pentaho_temp_path/$sessionkey"/"$(basename "$file" .gz)" & ; done ; wait

Comment: @ThibaultLEPAUL depending on the number of files, that could easily crash the machine, and if doing it over a network, disrupt all users of the network. Not something to suggest without knowing more context. (PS. you would want `for file ...; zcat ... & done` and not `& ;`, that's a syntax error).

Comment: Will not work as is because mv target filename is not stripped from parent dir

Comment: @ThibaultLEPAUL oh wow, of course! I had completely missed that and also didn't notice you mentioned it in your previous comment. I... need to learn to read. Fixed now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
for file in "$short_filename"/*.gz; do
  zcat "$file" > "$pentaho_temp_path/$sessionkey/$(basename "$file" .gz)"
done
```

- avoid piping `ls` output
- filter only .gz extensions
- parse full path to isolate file name without extension `basename "$fullpath" .gz`

if you are sure that no filename contains newlines, you can pipe them to parallelize the process:

```
myzcat(){ zcat "$1" > "$pentaho_temp_path/$sessionkey/$(basename "$1" .gz)"; }

ls "$short_filename"/*.gz | parallel myzcat
```

- use pipe instead of list model
- define a local function that takes one single argument
- run as many parallel processes as there are processors

Comment: FYI: `-d'\n'` is default.